# Python pandas extract variables from dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

What is the best way to convert DataFrame columns into variables. I have a condition for bet placement and I use head(n=1)

```
back_bf_lay_bq = bb[(bb['bf_back_bq_lay_lose_net'] > 0) & (bb['bq_lay_price'] < 5) & (bb['bq_lay_price'] != 0) & (bb['bf_back_liquid'] > bb['bf_back_stake']) & (bb['bq_lay_liquid'] > bb['bq_lay_horse_win'])].head(n=1)
```

I would like to convert columns into variables and pass them to API for bet placement. So I convert back_bf_lay_bq to dictionary and extract values

```
    #Bets placements
    dd = pd.DataFrame.to_dict(back_bf_lay_bq, orient='list')

    #Betdaq bet placement
    bq_selection_id = dd['bq_selection_id'][0]
    bq_lay_stake = dd['bq_lay_stake'][0]
    bq_lay_price = dd['bq_lay_price'][0]
    bet_type = 2
    reset_count = dd['bq_count_reset'][0]
    withdrawal_sequence = dd['bq_withdrawal_sequence'][0]
    kill_type = 2

    betdaq_request = betdaq_api.PlaceOrdersNoReceipt(bq_selection_id,bq_lay_stake,bq_lay_price,bet_type,reset_count,withdrawal_sequence,kill_type)
```

I do not think that it is the most efficient way and it brings a bug from time to time
bq_selection_id = dd['bq_selection_id'][0]
IndexError: list index out of range

So can you suggest a better way to get values from DataFrame and pass them to API?

Comment: Could you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It's a bit hard to understand how is your `back_bf_lay_bq` and `bb` looks like.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you could use `iloc` to get your first row and then slice your dataframe with your columns subset and pass that to your variables. Something like that:

```
bq_selection_id, bq_lay_stake, bq_lay_price, withdrawal_sequence = back_bf_lay_bq[['bq_selection_id', 'bq_lay_stake', 'bq_lay_price', 'withdrawal_sequence']].iloc[0]
```

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I need